# Why is there a discrepancy in disk usage reported by df and du?

Tags: linux, centos, disk-usage

I have a *Linux CentOS* server, the OS+packages used around *5GB*. Then, I transferred *97GB* data from a Windows server to two folders on this Linux server, after calculated the disk usage, I see the total size of the two folders is larger than the disk used size.

Run `du -sh` on each folder, one use *50GB*, the other one use *47GB*

But run `df -h`, the used space is *96GB*. (*50GB* + *47GB* + *5GB*) > *96GB*

Is there any problem? Those two folders contain lots of files (1 million+). Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/235599/i-am-confused-with-the-output-of-command-du-in-linux http://superuser.com/questions/94217/ls-and-du-shows-very-different-size

Comment: To be clear: are you running `du` and `df` on the copy on your Linux file system, or are you running them on a Windows/Samba mount point?

Comment: I was running du an df on the Linux server.

Comment: In my case it was due to large deleted file that were still open somehow. I checked with  `lsof|grep deleted which showed some very large files open by nginx, so I restarted `   service restart nginx` and I had a `tail -f` process still open on that file in a tmux terminal, so I stopped that. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766326/why-does-du-xshc-report-only-35gb-usage-while-my-100gb-disk-is-showing-as-full/766327#766327

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This](http://sysunconfig.net/aixtips/df_du_diff_out.txt) page gives some insight on why they have different values, however it seems to suggest that your `du` size should be the smaller of the two.

`df` uses total allocated blocks, while `du` only looks at files themselves, excluding metadata such as inodes, which still require blocks on the disk. Additionally, if a file is deleted while an application has it opened, `du` will report it as free space but `df` does not until the application exits.

Comment: this explains why `df` claims the disk is full... when it's not.

Comment: your comment is incorrect. if `df` says the disk is full, it is, at that point in time, full. files that have been deleted but are still held on to by running processes do consume space. that space cannot be used for other files.

Comment: `df` _used_ space doesn't include the inode table. It includes data for files that don't have a name in any directory, like deleted files, special files like the ext4 journal, or files masked by another mounted file system.

Answer (score 5):

When `du` is larger than `df`, the usual reason is "sparse blocks":  if a program doesn't actually write to a disk block but instead seeks past it, it gets a zero pointer in the inode's block allocation map and no actual disk space is reserved for it.  If you later write to it, an actual disk block will be allocated and the map will be changed to point to the new block.

Comment: I don't think sparse blocks are counted in `du`.

Comment: FWIW, in Linux coreutils (as of 4.5.8, way long ago), there's an `--apparent-size` option which takes sparse blocks into account.