# How does this directory use so much space

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage

Unix is not my native language and I'm getting confused by their concept of filesystems.

When I look at my free space I see:

```
/$ df -kh
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  7.1G  397M  95% /
none                  3.7G  120K  3.7G   1% /dev
none                  3.7G  4.0K  3.7G   1% /dev/shm
none                  3.7G   48K  3.7G   1% /var/run
none                  3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /var/lock
/dev/xvdf             100G   19G   82G  19% /db
/dev/xvdg             100G   15G   86G  15% /images
/dev/xvdb             414G  199M  393G   1% /mnt
```

To me this means all files and directories under /db is on filesystem xvdf, everything under /images is on xvdg and everything under /mnt is on xvdb. Everything else is on xvda1.

However, xvda1 has only 7.9G of space. So why does

```
/$ sudo du -sh var
25G     var
```

show me that /var is taking up 25G? I thought at first that maybe it's counting the contents at the destinations of symbolic links but I know a few directories down there's a symbolic link to the /images directory and that's got 86G of content so var should be >86G if symbolic links are followed.

So how can /var take up 25G on a drive that has only 7.9G?

btw, this is an ubuntu instance running in amazon's EC2, if that's significant.

Comment: If you run `du` without -s it will tell you the space each file consumes under /var. `sudo du -h /var > /tmp/foo` and then look through /tmp/foo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a discrepancy in disk usage reported by df and du?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-df-and-du)

Comment: Sparse files is the most likely explanation. Run `du /var` and check where the big stuff is to see what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you proper answer of your trouble.

> du -ch --max-depth=1 -x /var

`-x` will show only data usage of one file-system so skipping other filesystem's content from /var directory

`--max-depth=1` will give data usage of only first level e.g. /var/a /var/b and so on

Comment: Yes, this provides values that are much more reasonable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the output of df,

> /dev/xvdg             100G   15G   86G  15% /images

Only 15G were used in the /images.

Comment: Good catch. yes, I looked at the wrong column. So, perhaps du was following symbolic links.

Comment: Yeah, that is weird, du doesn't following symbolic links by default. Could you check with --no-dereference suggested by Jari Laamanen?

Comment: I tried it and it had no effect. With or without --no-dereference du reported var using 23G (on a 7.9G drive). The command given by SHW however shows var as using a more believable 480M.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `var` is not a symbolic link to any other file system.

```
 /$ ls -ld var
 drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Jun 22 02:13 var
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe var includes links to other installation directories. du -sh shows the size of all the followed links.

Comment: But not the link to the images directory? for some reason?

Comment: It might be a matter of inode ("hard") versus symbolic ("soft") links. This might help, from (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html): "By default, when a symbolic link is encountered on the command line or in the file hierarchy, du shall count the size of the symbolic link (rather than the file referenced by the link), and shall not follow the link to another portion of the file hierarchy."

Comment: Hard links cannot cross file system boundaries, so they are not to blame. You can try to use the parameter `--no-dereference` for `du` to force it not to follow any symbolic links. However, I doubt this is the issue, since it is the default already.

Comment: When I added --no-dereference it had no effect, which is what you'd expect I guess if --no-dereference was the default.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that you need to run `fsck` to fix the discrepancy.

I only mention it for completeness, but I still suspect something else is more likely. Afer a while if you still haven't found anything then you should give this a try.