# df vs. du: why so much difference?

Tags: disk-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there a discrepancy in disk usage reported by df and du?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-df-and-du)

`df` says 8.9G used by the partition mounted in `/`

```
:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       227G  8.9G  207G   5% /
```

However, a `du` in `/` yields a **much** smaller number.

```
:~# du -chs /
5.5G    /
5.5G    total
```

I was expecting a smaller number, but why is to **so much** smaller?

Comment: Which OS/filesystem? Just "UNIX" isn't very .. precise.

Answer (score 39):

Take a look at [du vs. df difference](https://serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference)

Here is a more thorough explanation: http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/12/why-du-and-df-display-different-values.html

Basically, `df` reads the superblock only and trusts it completely.  `du` reads each object and sums them up.

Also, a running process can keep a deleted file open. This means the space will still be reserved and seen by `df`, but since `du` will no longer see a reference to that file in the directory tree, it cannot see those reserved blocks.

Comment: The page you link to is wrong.  `du` shows block usage by default, not file size.  You have to do `du -b` or `du --apparent-size` to get the effect you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Probably `df` is accounting for all the space allocated for inodes and other administrative overhead, whereas `du` is just accounting for the space used by the files.