# Why is ncdu reporting different data from df?

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, measure

`df -h` prints:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        59G  6.6G   50G  12% /
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G  9.0M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   54M  199M  22% /boot
tmpfs           391M     0  391M   0% /run/user/1000
```

while `ncdu /` prints:

```
Total disk usage:   1.8 GiB  Apparent size:   1.8 GiB  Items: 176500
```

Why is one reporting 6.6+ GiB used while the other reports only `1.8 GiB`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage)

Comment: No, as it doesn't mention `ncdu`.

Comment: `ncdu` is (per its own manual) a curses-based version of `du`. Questions of `df` vs. `du` (like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45771/108618)) are well explained by what I linked to.

Comment: I see. But it still doesn't answer this. It says that `df` "does not always take all the control data of the filesystem into account", but in my case, it actually reports less, not more. And I don't think that the difference should be this big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `df` is based on filesystem-level statistics, whereas `ncdu` (and a regular `du`) generate their results by scanning through directories, reading the sizes of individual files, and summarizing that.

If the `du`-style commands are run as a non-root user, they won't necessary have full access to all directories, and so may not be able to see everything (use `sudo ncdu` in this case).

Try running `du -hs /` and comparing its results to the "total disk usage" reported by `ncdu /`. You may find the results are similar... and with `du`, you might also see messages about a bunch of directories the command is unable to access and so fails to take into account. The same is probably true of `ncdu`, but it just hides the error messages.

Also, it seems to me that `ncdu` might not have been updated to understand the virtual filesystems of modern Linux distributions, and may become confused by them. On my Debian 10 system, `ncdu /` reports:

```
Total disk usage:  75.6 GiB  Apparent size: 128.1 TiB  Items: 469143
```

In my case, the "Apparent size" is clearly nonsensical and useless. The "Total disk usage" is about the same as what I get with `du -hs /`... but because this includes a number of RAM-based virtual filesystems (`devtmpfs`, `tmpfs`), this number is also unlikely to be very useful.

But if I restrict the command to one filesystem only (e.g. `ncdu -x /`), I seem to get more reasonable results, which also match the output of `du -shx /` to within a rounding error, and also the output of `df -h` when remembering that a filesystem may need some space for its internal metadata.

Another possible source of errors would be if you're using advanced filesystem features like BTRFS filesystem snapshots. Sure, you might have only 1.8 GiB of files on your root filesystem, but if the filesystem also contains two snapshots of its previous states, the total amount of disk space used might be up to 3x what the sum of the size of files would lead you (and any `du`-like command) to expect.

Since the `df` command gets its information by asking the filesystem driver, the larger "used" value reported by it might include the snapshots, which could be otherwise invisible until accessed with the proper method.