# Disk space is missing

Tags: disk-usage, disk, ssd

I've been running a program lately that creates about 100-200GB of temp files each time. When this runs I'm often now running out of disk space...but I'm really not.

When I run `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  6.3G  2.9M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/data-root  912G  693G  174G  81% /
tmpfs                   32G  178M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2             163M  163M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1362
/dev/loop1             241M  241M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1373
/dev/nvme1n1p1         467M  228M  205M  53% /boot
/dev/loop4              56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop0             374M  374M     0 100% /snap/anbox/186
/dev/loop5              98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
/dev/loop6              98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
/dev/loop7             147M  147M     0 100% /snap/code/47
/dev/loop3             143M  143M     0 100% /snap/code/48
/dev/loop8             166M  166M     0 100% /snap/electron-mail/26
/dev/loop9              61M   61M     0 100% /snap/gmail-desktop/16
/dev/loop10             55M   55M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop11             93M   93M     0 100% /snap/insomnia/105
/dev/loop12             93M   93M     0 100% /snap/insomnia/109
/dev/loop13            177M  177M     0 100% /snap/postman/127
/dev/loop14             11M   11M     0 100% /snap/helm/302
/dev/loop16             92M   92M     0 100% /snap/go/6633
/dev/loop15            141M  141M     0 100% /snap/slack/30
/dev/loop17             92M   92M     0 100% /snap/go/6439
/dev/loop18            174M  174M     0 100% /snap/postman/128
/dev/loop19            113M  113M     0 100% /snap/gmail-desktop/12
/dev/loop20            163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop21            170M  170M     0 100% /snap/spotify/42
/dev/loop22            164M  164M     0 100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop23            9.9M  9.9M     0 100% /snap/helm/292
/dev/loop24            138M  138M     0 100% /snap/slack/29
/dev/loop25            9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/kubectl/1634
/dev/loop26            168M  168M     0 100% /snap/electron-mail/27
/dev/loop27             56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop28            9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/kubectl/1647
/dev/loop29             63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop30            162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
tmpfs                  6.3G   24K  6.3G   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs                  6.3G  124K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/sda1              932G  664G  268G  72% /media/work/WD Elements SE 25FE
```

As you can see I have ~912GB `/` and it's saying I've used 693G. But that is NOT the case in reality. See below, showing I'm barely using 500GB

[image: screenshot of baobab showing disk usage]

When I run `sudo lsof +L1` I get https://pastebin.com/WD5qTEYW (None of the files listed look interesting, i.e. none relate to the tmp files the program I'm running creates)

I've also tried adding `touch /forcefsck` and rebooting, it looks like fsck does not run on boot for whatever reason. I also tried adding fsck to the grub config, same result, it does not run:

```
>> sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/data-root|grep check
Last checked:             Sun Nov 24 23:35:00 2019
```

So after Googling around and trying the above over and over I'm out of ideas. Can anyone figure out what's going on here?

Here's my OS info.

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="20.04 LTS"
ID=pop
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS"
```

HDD is a `Samsung 970 EVO Plus 1 TB PCIe NVMe M.2 (2280) Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) (MZ-V7S1T0)`

Comment: There's quite a lot of questions on this site about [differing outputs between `du` and `df`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45771/df-vs-du-why-so-much-difference/45772). Have you looked through any of them?

Comment: @Richard There's nothing to “fix”. You have files taking up disk space. That's not something you can fix.

Comment: If your post contains sensitive information that should not have been posted in the first place, editing will not help as the [revision history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/617756/revisions) is still visible. Instead, look at [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) in the help center.

Comment: Yes, please stop vandalizing your post. If there is a problem with it, raise a custom moderator flag and let us know. This can help future visitors to the site, so we don't allow users to remove useful posts.

Comment: If you need a post to be deleted, you need to explain _why_. We don't delete things lightly and when you post here you licence the content to the site. So, if you really need this to be deleted, please flag _and explain why_.

Answer (score 8):

> I've been running a program lately that creates about 100-200GB of temp files each time. When this runs I'm often now running out of disk space...

> ```
> /dev/mapper/data-root  912G  693G  174G  81% /
> ```

You have 174GB free but you need up to 200GB, so you will run out of disk space. You need to make room.

> but I'm really not.

Yes, you are. The numbers are above.

> it's saying I've used 693G. But that is NOT the case in reality. See below, showing I'm barely using 500GB

No, the figure from `df` is accurate. It doesn't get more real than that.

That screenshot evidently only counts files that are readable from your user account, since it isn't showing a figure against `/root` and `/lost+found` which you can't read. So you have 435GB that are readable from your account, plus ~258GB that isn't. If you want to know what's using that space, you need to go digging with administrator rights. Run that GUI tool as administrator (`sudo baobab`) or run

```
sudo du -x -h / | sort -h >du.txt
```

[Other complications are possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage) (in particular, you should make sure to have a 5% margin, i.e. don't fill your disk to more than 95%) but first you need to trust the correct figure (the one from `df`) instead of the partial figure.

Comment: @Richard Let it complete. The most likely location for files that you can't see without being root is under `/var`.

Comment: Running `du` as root can still miss some files, if they are still in use by a process but have been unlinked already.

Comment: @BrianBi Yes, that's one of the other complications I reference. It's not likely to be happening here since the used space survives a reboot. (It could be happening if something runs at boot time and creates large files which it immediately deletes, but that's unlikely.)