# Invisible file footprint (du vs df)

Tags: files, nfs, disk-usage

I am aware of the [expected reasons that du and df will report differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-df-and-du), however I cannot imagine these would justify the discrepancy I am seeing:

```
[root@example.com mynfsmount]# df -h /opt/mynfsmount
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
192.168.0.92:/data/export/examplecom
                      3.0T  2.7T  391G  88% /opt/mynfsmount
[root@example.com mynfsmount]# du -sh /opt/mynfsmount
13G     /opt/mynfsmount
```

i.e. df is reporting ~300 times the usage du reports.

It may be significant that the NFS server is a Synology box, the host is Centos 5.11 (erk!) and there is no lost+found directory in /opt/mynfsmount. This is a system I have inherited and there is little information available about how much data is expected to be there.

Currently lsof only reports a single deleted file still open.

Any suggestions of what I try next?

Comment: What about running `du` or `df` on the NFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is expected behaviour.

Lets say you have a server with a filesystem mounted as `/foo` and that filesytem contains two directories `bar` and `baz` giving you `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/baz/`.  Lets say:

- `/foo` is a 100GB file system
- `/foo/bar/` contains 10GB of files
- `/foo/baz/` contains 20GB of files
- leaving 70GB free.

If you then export `/foo/bar` through NFS.  And mount it on a client as `/mnt/bar`.  Then on the clint you execute both:

```
df -h /mnt/bar
du -hs /mnt/bar
```

I would expect:

- `df` to show 30GB used, 70GB free, 100GB totoal.
- `du` to show only 10GB used.

The other 20GB has not been exposed through NFS, but it will show up on your usage when interrogated in `df`.  This is normal behavior for remote file system protocols on most operating systems.

In short, `df` shows the statistics for the whole file system as mounted on the remote server.  `du` shows the total size of files you have access to.

---

*Note:* There are many other reasons `du` may not have access to some files contained on a file system.  A couple of other reasons include:

- It is possible to delete ([unlink](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink)) a file while a program is still writing to it.  If this happens the file remains on disk until all references (including open file handles) are removed.  `du` cannot find these because they have no filename.  But they will still have an inode and so still show up when checked with `df`.
- Likewise filesystems can occasionally become corrupted.  Files can still exist after all references have been closed due to corruption.  This is one good reason to perform semi-regular [fsck](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck) checks on your disk.

By far the most likely in your scenario is the export example I showed at the top. But if you are concerned then do unmount and `fsck` your disk.