# Discrepancy between file size and disks occupied

Tags: ubuntu, disk

I created a file with a single "A" character in it.
Ran the stat command and got as part of the information:

`Size: 2             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file`

Why does a 2 bytes file occupy 8 512 bytes blocks on disk?

Also,is there a command that shows you how big one logic block is?

Thanks!

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-df-and-du among other

Comment: Oh, and by the way, welcome to U&L, you are asking a valid question, but often asked, just follow links I gave.