# du shows more used space than available space showed by df

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

I have a remote linux server on which I'm seeing the following weird behaviour:

When I use `du -ch /somedrive` to get the total occupied space, I get 16TB.
But when I use `df -h /somedrive` to get the total size of space, I get 10TB, and 500GB still available.

How is the total drive size (by `df`: 10TB) less than the total occupied space (by `du`: 16TB)?

---

Here is what the output of `df -Th /somedrive` looks like:

```
Filesystems         Type   Size   Used   Avail   Use%   Mounted on
/mapr/somedrive     nfs    10TB   9.5TB  500T    95%    /somedrive
```

---

Here is what the output of `df -Th` looks like:

```
Filesystems         Type   Size   Used   Avail   Use%   Mounted on
/mapr/somedrive     nfs    1.9P   1.4P   560T    72%    /somedrive
```

Comment: Possible: Compression being used on the drive.

Comment: Or this maybe: [Why is there a discrepancy in disk usage reported by df and du?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-df-and-du)

Comment: could be deleted files that are still open. check with `lsof | grep deleted`