# Why does du -xshc report only 35GB usage while my 100GB disk is showing as full?

Tags: disk-usage

My SSD-disk on my server is full although `du` doesn't show it.

```
df -h|head
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2       98G   93G     0 100% /
```

although:

```
du -xhcs --apparent-size /                                                                                              
35G     /                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
35G     total
```

I also checked with `ncdu -x /` which gives also only 35GB

How can I further debug this?

Comment: That question has been asked literally hundreds of times. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/9612?lq=1 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/120311?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it is a large deleted file that is still open somehow:

```
#lsof|grep deleted|grep nginx/error.log
COMMAND       PID     TID TASKCMD               USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE    SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
2x
nginx     1896696                               root    5w      REG              202,2 62868951040    1344848 /var/log/nginx/error.log~ (deleted)
16x
nginx     1896697                           www-data    2w      REG              202,2 62868951040    1344848 /var/log/nginx/error.log~ (deleted)
```

To free this deleted file restart the process that could have it open in this case

```
service restart nginx
```

or see if there is a `tail -f` process still open on that file in any terminal session (e.g. tmux)

Also check for loop devices with

```
losetup -a
```